cannot push to gitlab from a copied repository
I have two machines. I have gitlab repo cloned on one of them and is working just fine.
Recently I tar zipped one folder from this machine and installed the same on the other machine. (.git directory got copied along with it).
On this new machine,
git add, diff, commit and other commands worked fine; however git push did not work at all. It throws following error:
remote: The project you were looking for could not be found or you don't have permission to view it.
fatal: repository 'https://gitlab.com/<userid>/<reponame>.git/' not found

How should I approach this to get it solved. The repo is working just fine from the other machine.

You likely need to add your ssh key for the remote gitlab server on the new machine Gitlab SSH Instructions. If you have the proper key stored on the new machine, and you have added it with:
ssh-add <key-path>

Then you should revoke permissions on your previous key and generate a new one and repeat the steps.
